# How to query on a Pointer field in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a "GCUR_OBSERVATION" collection which has a field called `Location` that is referenced to an item in another collection called "GCUR_LOCATION".

An example of a document in the GCUR_OBSERVATION collection is

```
{
    "_id": "ZOcQnZjXuf",
    "_updated_at": "2016-02-28 14:35:04",
    "AreaHeight": 20,
    "Comments": "Test",
    "_created_at": "2016-02-28 14:35:04",
    "ObservationDate": "2016-02-28 14:31:00",
    "AreaCuring": 0,
    "_p_Location": "GCUR_LOCATION$Iv9vfS88aD",
    "Rainfall": 50.4,
    "ObservationStatus": 0,
    "AreaFuelLoad": 2,
    "AreaCover": 70,
    "_p_Observer": "_User$96n85UtpGz"
  }
```

My question is how to make a query on the `Location` field by `_id`. I tried, for example, { "_p_Location.$id" : "Iv9vfS88aD" } but it returned nothing. How to construct the MongoDB sql string by `db.find("")`? What I need is a query that can return this same document.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @SSDMS. Just wondering what is the correct query syntax for a query on the Location field by its _id?

Comment: What is the expected result of your query?

Comment: I know what are inside the collection. What I need is a query command that is expected to return the a document by its Location _id which references to another document in the Location collection.

Comment: With the sample document with have here, what the output document look like? Please edit your question to include the output document.

Comment: @alextc , if you are wanting to query collection `GCUR_OBSERVATION` by `_p_Location` field you could do: `db.GCUR_OBSERVATION.find({_p_Location:"GCUR_LOCATION$Iv9vfS88aD"})` See [db.coll.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) for more info.  If this is not what you are after, please include some desirable output to clarify.